# Simplifying $\frac{\sec x + \csc x}{1 + \tan x}$ to an expression in terms of $\sin x$

Tags: trigonometry

i'm having trouble getting this one started please.

> Simplify the first trigonometric expression by writing the simplified form in terms of the second expression.
> $$\frac{\sec x + \csc x}{1 + \tan x} \qquad \sin x$$

I have tried converting to

$$\frac{\dfrac{1}{\cos x} + \dfrac{1}{\sin x}}{1 + \dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x}}$$

Then
$$\frac{ 1 + \dfrac{\cos x}{\sin x}}{\cos x + \sin x}$$

But if I progress this further I cannot seem to yield a result and I'm not sure if I'm heading in the right direction witht this.

The answer is apparently, $\dfrac{1}{\sin x}$

Comment: $ \displaystyle \frac{ 1 + \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}} {\cos x + \sin x} = \frac{ 1 + \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}} {\sin x \cdot (1 + \frac{\cos x}{\sin x})}$

Comment: Oh yeah, that's really good. Do you want to put that in an answer and I will vote it up? @MathLover

Comment: @Bucephalus As a general tip, if you know what the expression will simplify to, then try to force the expression to make it look like the desired result, e.g. in this case, that amounts to factoring out a $\sin x$ on the bottom from the very start

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes sense @Golden_Ratio . Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Bucephalus ok. I just added an answer.

Comment: Alternatively, $\frac{\sin x + \cos x}{\sin x \cos x + \sin^2 x} = \frac{\sin x + \cos x}{\sin x (\cos x + \sin x)} =  \frac{1}{\sin x}.$

Comment: Thank you @TobyMak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can rewrite numerator as,

$ \displaystyle \csc x + \sec x = \csc x \cdot \left(1 + \frac{\sec x}{\csc x}\right)$

$ \displaystyle~~~~ = \csc x \left(1 + \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\right) = \csc x \left(1 + \tan x\right)$

So, $\displaystyle \frac {\csc x + \sec x}{1 + \tan x} = \frac{1}{\sin x}$

Comment: That's really good. Thanks @MathLover

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\frac{1}{\cos x}+\frac{1}{\sin x}}{1+\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}} &=\frac{\frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\cos x \sin x}}{\frac{\cos x+\sin x}{\cos x}} \\
&=\frac{1}{\sin x}
\end{aligned}
$$